# How can I change state specific to item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

I am currently working on creating a table with customer information in each of the rows. The last column is titled 'Remove', and when clicked it should trigger the removal of the row. Each row will have a button that says "Yes", that when you click it it will change to "Confirm" and finally the last click will trigger the removal. Currently the way I have it set up, it works as I want it to but when you click one of the buttons, all of the buttons do the same action; so in this case, if you click on one button all of them will change to "Confirm" instead of having only the button for that specific row change.

I know this is because I don't have a unique identifier/index so it's changing the state for every button. I am currently passing in the index but I'm not sure how to use it. I am not sure how to accomplish what I need and would love any advice on how I could change state for a specific row. There needs to be an initial state for the `button color`, `button text`, `first_click` and `second_click` and then when the customer clicks on the button for that row, the state will change. Below are the code snippets for the overall ideal behavior that needs to be changed to be specific per-row.

Setting initial state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        buttonColor: "#FD8F83", 
        buttonText: "Yes", 
        first_click: false, 
        second_click: false,
    };
  }
```

Set state on click:

```
  handleClick(i) {
    if (this.state.first_click === false) {
      console.log("first click");
      this.setState({
        buttonColor: "#A4D87C",
        buttonText: "Confirm?",
        first_click: true
      });
    } else if (this.state.first_click === true && this.state.second_click === false) {
      console.log("second click");
      this.setState({
        second_click: true,
      });
    } else {
      console.log("third or more click");
    }
    }
```

Part of the return from App's render function:

```
<tbody>
          {this.props.initialCustomers.map((customer, index) => {
              return (
                <Customer 
                    name={customer.customer} 
                    fb_un={customer.fbun} 
                    em_un={customer.emun} 
                    key={customer._id}
                    id={customer._id}
                    handleClick={function() {this.handleClick(index)}.bind(this)}
                    buttonColor={this.state.buttonColor}
                    buttonText={this.state.buttonText}
                    first_click={this.state.first_click}
                    second_click={this.state.second_click}
                />
              );
            })
          }
</tbody>
```

I apologize if this is obvious, I am new to React.

In a separate project that I did on Team Treehouse, we set state with `this.state.players[index].score += delta;` and `this.setState(this.state);`.  However, when I use a similar method on this project (for instance, `this.state.buttonColor = "A4D87C"`) I get the below error. I also tried many other things online and cannot get it to work, I could post what I've done if it'd be helpful but I wasn't sure it'd matter if it didn't work.

> Do not mutate state directly. Use setState() 
>   react/no-direct-mutation-state

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if I can provide any other information. Thank you!

Comment: Where is the players loop that increments the score by delta?

Comment: Hi @ReyHaynes - that is a separate project that we did in the Team Treehouse React course. I just wanted to show the method that I tried. Even if I use this.state.buttonColor = "#A4D87C", it throws that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create a component ButtonRow. 
Each rows, get his own button with his own internal state.

```
class ButtonRow extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            state: 0; // 0: display 'Yes'; 1: display Confirm
        }

    }

    removeRow = () => {
        if(this.state.state === 1) {
            this.props.deleteRow(this.props.index);
        }
        else {
            const currentState = this.state.state;
            this.setState({state: currentState + 1});
        }
    };



    render() {
        const differentDisplay = ['Yes','Confirm'];
        <button onClick={ () => this.props.removeRow() }>
            {differentDisplay[this.state.state]}
        </button>

    }

};
```

you call the ButtonComponent inside your component Customer and you provide your remove function and the index of the array corresponding to the row.

Comment: Thank you SO much for the help! I was able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the players loop you are running but it might be fixed with this...

Replace:

```
this.state.players[index].score += delta;
this.setState(this.state);
```

With:

```
let { players } = this.state;
players[index].score += delta;
this.setState({ players });
```

Comment: That is a separate project that we did in the Team Treehouse React course. I just wanted to show the method that I tried. Even if I use this.state.buttonColor = "#A4D87C", it throws that error. I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: For `this.state.buttonColor = "#A4D87C"`, you use `this.setState({ buttonColor: "#A4D87C" });`

Comment: @DallasHuggins No matter what the situation is, don't use any assignment operators (=, +=, -=, etc.) after state has been set initially. You have to use `setState` to not get the warnings.

Comment: thanks! I did see that and that's how I'm currently setting state. The problem was more that the initial way I was taught isn't the way you do it anymore so I'm not sure how to fix the problem I'm on.

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash functions for a better and null free code.
Even better if you manage state using immutableJs.

This is one way to achieve what you want.

```
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';

// Cloning players.
const players = cloneDeep(this.state.players);

// Updating its values.
players[index].score += delta;

// setting the state with the new cloned players
this.setState({
    players
})
```

Comment: There's actually no need to import another module to do this when `let { players } = this.state` or `let players = {...this.state.players}` achieves the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment by @Leeroy_Wonkledge I was able to get this working. Below is what my ButtonRow component looks like.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class ButtonRow extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            buttonColor: "#FD8F83",
            button: 0 
        };
    }

    deleteRow = (i) => {
        console.log("delete row", i);
    }

    removeRow = (i) => {
        if(this.state.button === 1) {
            const currentState = this.state.button;
            this.setState({
                button: currentState + 1
            });
            this.deleteRow(this.props.index);
        }
        else if (this.state.button === 0) {
            const currentState = this.state.button;
            this.setState({
                button: currentState + 1,
                buttonColor: "#A4D87C",
            });
        }
    };

    render() {
        const differentDisplay = ['Yes','Confirm'];
        return (
            <button 
            style={{backgroundColor: this.state.buttonColor}} 
            onClick={ () => this.removeRow() }>
                {differentDisplay[this.state.button]}
            </button>
        );
    }
}

ButtonRow.propTypes = {
    index: PropTypes.number.isRequired
};

export default ButtonRow;
```